# C++ const pointers - Unexplained behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have this piece of code:

```
const int x = 7;
const int &y = x;

int *z = (int*)&y;
*z = 8;

cout << x<< endl;
cout << y<< endl;
cout << *z<< endl;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
7
8
8
```

I know that one should not remove the const as I did above. However, why does x print out 7? I've only created a single var, so if the output shows 7 and 8, then then there should be 2 vars created. How come there be 2 different numbers printed.

Comment: Probably adding `volatile` would to `x` would change this behavior but this is still undefined behavior and you should avoid it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know that one should not remove the const as I did above.

Right.  Doing so is undefined behaviour, which means *anything* can happen.  (More precisely, creating `z` is not undefined behaviour; modifying `x` through it is.)

> However, why does x print out 7? I've only created a single var, so if the output shows 7 and 8, then then there should be 2 vars created. How come there be 2 different numbers printed.

Reasoning about undefined behaviour is weird - but it can be useful to understand what is happening for debugging purposes.  It this case, what has almost certainly happened, is that the compiler has optimized:

```
cout << x<< endl;
```

to

```
cout << 7 << endl;
```

because there is no way you can legitimately modify the value of x.  You then illegitimately modify the value of x, and manage to print out the new value.

### Important Note

Do not attempt to rely on this behaviour; as I said above, it is only useful for debugging purposes.  If the compiler changes it might get better at optimization and just print 7 for all values (because `*z = 8` is undefined behaviour), or it might put `x` in read-only memory (and cause a access violation), or it might end up printing 8 for all values, or anything else might happen.

Comment: Thanks Martin, your answer best explains what I'm looking for. I thought that something like this might occur.

Comment: Up voting. I tested it in clion 2017.1 on OS X in debug mode and the variable observer said `x` is 8 after the modification. So I guess the reason you got 7 in output is that compiler optimized the variable identifier to number literal because it supposed `x` is `const`. And one should not rely on this optimizing feature that some specific compilers provide. One may get compiler error or runtime error or unchanged "7" on some other compiler -- that's what 'undefined behavior' means.

Comment: @NandiinBao - By curious coincidence, your comment says almost exactly what I appended to my answer :-).  Great minds think alike!

Comment: Ahh ok. I used GCC.

Answer (score 3):

> However, why does x print out 7?

Modifying a const object has undefined behaviour.

Comment: But if 8 is printed, does that mean that C++ creates an internal variable, hence you will have 4 additional bytes allocated?

Comment: @goocreations - No, it means the behavior is undefined. C++ makes no promises for anything particular to happen, and different compilers can do anything they like.

Comment: @goocreations no, you can not make such conclusion. To find out what the compiler has chosen to do, you can inspect the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Casting away const-ness and using the pointer to modify a const object has undefined behavior. You are seeing the result of that.

The standard even has almost the same example you posted.

[[dcl.type.cv/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4)

> Except that any class member declared mutable can be modified, any
>   attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in
>   undefined behavior. [ Example:
>
> ```
> const int ci = 3;                       // cv-qualified (initialized as required)
> ci = 4;                                 // ill-formed: attempt to modify const
>
> int i = 2;                              // not cv-qualified
> const int* cip;                         // pointer to const int
> cip = &i;                               // OK: cv-qualified access path to unqualified
> *cip = 4;                               // ill-formed: attempt to modify through ptr to const
>
> int* ip;
> ip = const_cast<int*>(cip);             // cast needed to convert const int* to int*
> *ip = 4;                                // defined: *ip points to i, a non-const object
>
> const int* ciq = new const int (3);     // initialized as required
> int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq);        // cast required
> *iq = 4;                                // undefined: modifies a const object
> ```
>
> For another example,
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   mutable int i;
>   int j;
> };
> struct Y {
>   X x;
>   Y();
> };
>
> const Y y;
> y.x.i++;                                // well-formed: mutable member can be modified
> y.x.j++;                                // ill-formed: const-qualified member modified
> Y* p = const_cast<Y*>(&y);              // cast away const-ness of y
> p->x.i = 99;                            // well-formed: mutable member can be modified
> p->x.j = 99;                            // undefined: modifies a const member
> ```
>
> — end example ]